# Two Highlighted Content web parts side by side

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, highlighted-content-web-part

I have created a new page where I have added a highlighted content web part linked to one of my document libraries and it filters by most viewed files.

I want to add another  highlighted content web part linked to the same library but this time showing the trending items of that library.

Can I move the content web parts so they are side by side ?

I want them to have this format. (web-parts side by side)

[image]

As it for now it looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below demo to split the zone as two slide zones.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. I got another question. Is there a way that the scrolling bar is shown at the top and not on the bottom´? I have added a document's library most viewed items and need to go all the way down to scroll and see the rest of the coulmns